# Image to text online converter

Tags: webapp-rec, images, text, ocr

Can anyone recommend a website (free tool) where I can enter an image (it contains some text) and get back text.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for online OCR (Optical Character Recognition) services. The following free online services may help you:

- [onlineocr.net](http://www.onlineocr.net/)
- [free-ocr.com](http://www.free-ocr.com/)
- [newocr.com](http://www.newocr.com/)
- [free-online-ocr.com](http://free-online-ocr.com/)
- [ocrconvert.com](http://www.ocrconvert.com/)
- [myfreeocr.com](http://www.MyFreeOCR.com/)

Comment: +1 No one did this job, except this one: free-ocr.com (2-3 mistakes - it's ok). I have a big question, is there any non-free tool that do it perfect? :)
Thanks, Mehper!

Comment: @igor: You're welcome. AFAIK, [Abbyy FineReader](http://finereader.abbyyonline.com/en/Help/AboutFinereaderOnline) offers a premium (paid) online service.

Comment: I added my own website MyFreeOCR.com - it is a free online ocr service.

Answer (score 2):

2 other free online OCR services:

- [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=176692&hl=en) can convert
  images  with text into text
  documents.

  The maximum size for images (.jpg,
  .gif, .png) that it can handle is 2
  MB & each line of text in the image
  should ideally be of at least 10
  pixels height.
- [OCR Terminal](http://www.ocrterminal.com/) is an online OCR
  service that can convert image
  formats (TIFF, JPEG, GIF, BMP) to
  editable (.doc, .txt, .rtf) formats

Answer (score 0):

**http://online-ocr.net** is a free online OCR system supporting 29 languages and various input formats (I am on the development team of online-ocr.net).

Comment: Please disclose if you are affiliated with the site.